# How to free space on Time Machine on a Netgear NAS?

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine, nas, macos

I have obsolete time machine backup file in Netgear NAS with another one. I cannot so just format or erase whole disk. I just need to delete the non-used file from taking disk space. I am running 10.6.8 Snow leopard and I haven't found a way to delete it. TM does not recognize file anymore so I can't use the "star wars" to access it and delete. I tried to delete using view package but nothing seem to happen when deleting files one or many. Normal deleting does not seem to work.

Anyone done it? I need a proven solution!

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work:

http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=60831

```
$ cd /Volumes/ReadyNAS-1/
$ rm -rf macbook.sparsebundle
```

It took a while to delete 300 GB but worked, diskspace increased!